# Reload template using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a template like this,

```
.container-info
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      %a{:href => "#", "ui-sref" => ".container-big-trailer({value: '{{ trailer.link }}'})"} {{ trailer.link }} Load trailer

  .container-trailers
    %div{"ui-view" => "youtube_trailer"}
```

The `a` element loads my trailer state so that my template gets injected into the `youtube_trailer` view. But a movie can have multiple trailers, but when I click on a second trailer nothing happens since the state is allready loaded.

This is how my routing looks now,

```
.state('home.container-big',{
  url: '',
  views: {
    "container-big":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('home.container-big.container-big-trailer',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "youtube_trailer":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.value = $stateParams.value;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

A small html example to make it more clear,

`_movie-info.html.haml` template, `home.container-big` state,

First click,

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li> <-- clicked element
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ui-view="youtube_trailer"></div> <-- Loads this state `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` which injects the template into the `youtube_trailer` view.
```

Second click,

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li> <-- clicked element
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ui-view="youtube_trailer"></div> <-- this state should be reloaded.
```

I have tried adding a `$state.go` but I can figure out what the right values should be.

```
 controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
   $scope.value = $stateParams.value;
   $state.go('home.container-big.container-big-trailer', 
   $stateParams, {reload: 'container-big-trailer'});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transitionTo:

```
$state.transitionTo('state-name', $stateParams, {reload: true});
```

Comment: On what state should I use the `transitionTo` ?

Comment: Which state you want to reload?

Comment: My `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` because this injects the template that holds the youtube player. So when a different `a` is clicked I want to reload the `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` state (and thus the template).

Comment: So replace 'state-name' with the state that you want to reload.

Comment: That causes a infinite loop though.

Comment: Try $state.current.name